# Commerce engine logging stops working after around 30 mins

Tags: sitecore-commerce

In one of our e-commerce engine service environments, logging stops after about 30 minutes. The logging starts again once we reset the AppPool for the service. Other than the logs, there is no issue with the service. The storefront is able to communicate with it properly even after logging stops. This issue is only occurring in one environment.

Has anyone else experienced similar behavior or have any suggestions on what to look into?

Comment: did you set on app pool for that site the setting Start Mode:  AlwaysRunning ?

Comment: are you talking about commerce minions role?

Comment: no it is authoring role.

Answer (score 1):

There is no issue with logging since it logs on app startup. I faced the same issue with our Commerce instance. It was just logging at app startup but nothing after that even though the requests were being successfully executed. Just change your Minimum Default log level under config.json (config.Development.json if Development environment). It should be 'Information' and not only 'Warning' (Default case). Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks Durgesh, but log level is already Information and it is happening with Authoring role, which is right now configured with Sitecore as commerce engine endpoint. we can see logs updating for 30 mins so that means logging is working after startup.

Comment: That's weird. In order to narrow down the issue (whether IIS blocks I/O requests or application has something to do with it), can you try accessing the Commerce Auth Engine APIs through Postman (after 30 mins) and see the logs. If it logs, this will confirm that there is no issue from application end (CommerceAuth instance) and it has something to do with IIS. Please also check your Event logs after 30 mins. to ensure that there is no unhandled exceptions generated.